# Extracting a list from a string in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of JSON objects as a string.

```
str = "[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}]"
```

Is there any way to store the string as a list into a variable?

```
arr = [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}]
```

Comment: Use `json` module. `import json; arr = json.loads(str)`

Comment: @hurlenko it's not valid json because of the single quotes.

Comment: Yep, missed that. Well in this case a simple `arr = eval(str)` will work just fine

Comment: @hurlenko thanks for the help, but eval would fail if any value is null. json.load() should do the trick if we make the JSON valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To not be bother by the json-quote problem, just use `eval` or `ast.literal_eval`

```
value = eval(value)
```

---

Because to have valid JSON, you may have double quotes, then pass it to `json.loads`, but this could be a problem if you have a double or single quote in the content

```
value = "[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}]"
value = json.loads(value.replace("'", '"'))
```

Comment: This is likely to break if any of the string values contains `'`.

Answer (score 3):

you could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval
my_str = "[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}]"
arr = literal_eval(my_str)
arr
```

output:

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}]
```